# $X^3+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $I=(X^3+2)$ be the principal ideal of $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$ generated by $X^3+2$. Show that $X^3+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$.

Can someone give me the first step on how to do this please.
Also what is $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$? Is it just a polynomial with maximal degree of $7$ with coefficients of $\mathbb{F}$? Also what is $\mathbb{F}_7$?

Comment: If you don't care enough about us to read our rules, then why should we care about your question?

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$ most likely means polynomials (of all degrees) over *the field with seven elements* (aka $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: As with polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, multiplying two polynomials adds their degrees.  So if a cubic polynomial were reducible, it would have to be a product of a quadratic and a first-degree polynomial.  If you can rule that out, you have shown a cubic polynomial (over a field) is irreducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$ means the ring of polynomials in one variable over $\mathbb{F}_7$ the field with $7$ elements; this is basically $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.

A polynomial of degree $3$ that is reducible has a factor of degree $1$ and thus a root.

Check that your polynomial has no root, by simply plugging in all seven values.

Comment: when you say seven values, what are these 7 values? how are you supposed to know?

Comment: As it happens, there is only one finite field with seven elements (up to isomorphism), and more generally if $q$ is a positive power of a prime, there is exactly one field with exactly $q$ elements.  It is assumed you know how to do arithmetic modulo $7$, which gives you the field with seven elements.

Comment: @snowman As hardmath says,  all the elements of the base field, the field with seven elements.

Comment: I know how to do modulo but I still don't understand $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$. I know what it means to work within something like $\mathbb{Z}_7$. This would be {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} but I don't get it in this case....

Comment: can someone just write $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$ as a set please. maybe I will understand then

Comment: @snowman Try starting with the Wikipedia page on polynomial rings.  I think you'll need to understand that before you start thinking about ideals and quotients of those rings. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring

Comment: which part shall I read? because I don't think all of it applies to me.

Comment: @snowman sections 1 and 2

Comment: This is only telling me about K[X] where K is a field. I understand this. I just don't understand when there is a subscript on K. Please help me. I am desperate.

Comment: @snowman the subscribt is just there to tell you what the field is. You could write instead, let $K = \mathbb{F}_7 $. Now consider $K[X]$. An element of $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$ is of the form $a_0 + a_1X + a_2X^2 + \dots + a_kX^k$ where each $a_i$ is an element of $\mathbb{F}_7$. (That is informally you calculate modulo 7 with the $a_i$. Would you consider $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ instead you would calculate modulo 11 and so on.)